# Design matrix to test individual species effects in species mixture

Tags: experiment-design, model, contrasts

I have fields with species mixtures (for instance, species a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c), and I look at the effect of each species on a response Y. More specifically, I would like to compare the effect of individual species, either alone or in mixture.

```
>Y = rnorm(18,0,1)
>mixture= rep(c('a','b', 'c', 'a+b', 'a+c', 'b+c'), each = 3)
```

Thus I create variables A, B and C with :

- A = 1 when the mixture contains a (ie mixture = a or a+b or a+c); and 0 otherwise.
- Idem for variables C and B.

  ```
  >A = ifelse(mixture %in% c('a', 'a+b', 'a+c'), 1, 0)
  >B = ifelse(mixture %in% c('b', 'a+b', 'b+c'), 1, 0)
  >C = ifelse(mixture %in% c('c', 'a+c', 'b+c'), 1, 0)
  ```

  My plan was to build a design matrix from these 3 variables, that would then allow me to compare the effects of each species.

  ```
   >mm = model.matrix(~A+B+C+0)
   >summary(lm(Y~mm))
  Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
  (Intercept)  -0.8301     0.6221  -1.334    0.203  
  mmA           1.1636     0.4819   2.415    0.030 *
  mmB           0.8452     0.4819   1.754    0.101  
  mmC          -0.1005     0.4819  -0.208    0.838  
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  Residual standard error: 0.8347 on 14 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-squared:  0.4181,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2934 
  F-statistic: 3.353 on 3 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.04964
  ```

My questions :

1. My ddl are wrong, I should not have an intercept here, or at least my intercept should be one of my species. Should I just remove one species form the design matrix ?
2. Is there any way to do post-hoc tests on my species now, as I would have done with Tukey test or lsmeans ?

My objective afterwards is to add other explanatory variables and interactions in the model.